# terminal ask password but I cannot type nothing

Tags: command-line

unable to put anything in there. Is the password the same as administrator password?

Answer (score 2):

You can type, but no characters are shown. This is as designed. Just type your password and press Enter.

If you are doing `sudo ..`the password is the same as your login-password.